# Android Stripe payment

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am trying to make payments with stripe. Instead of using they're prebuilt ui design I wanted make my own ui design, so I found [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/integrating-stripe-into-your-android-app/) to teach me. I followed everything in the tutorial but I ran into some issues when I ran my app. My app ended up crashing and I got this error refering to this line in my code

> ```
>          Integer.valueOf(yearField.getText().toString()),
> ```

I'm not sure what the problem may be. Can someone please assit. Thanks in advance

This is the error message:

```java
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.clot, PID: 27954
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6308)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24949)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6615)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6308) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24949) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6615) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter brand
        at com.stripe.android.model.Card.<init>(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.myapp.colt.PaymentPagePractice.submitCard(PaymentPagePractice.java:126)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6308) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24949) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6615) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857) 
`
```

My code:

```java
public void submitCard(View view) {

     TextInputEditText cardNumberField = findViewById(R.id.textinputedittext_cardnumber);
     TextInputEditText monthField = findViewById(R.id.textinputedittext_month);
     TextInputEditText yearField =  findViewById(R.id.textinputedittext_year);
     TextInputEditText cvcField =  findViewById(R.id.textinputedittext_cvc);

     card=new Card(
             cardNumberField.getText().toString(),
             cvcField.getText().toString(),
             Integer.valueOf(monthField.getText().toString()),
             Integer.valueOf(yearField.getText().toString()),
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null, null,
             null,null,null,
             null,null,
             "usd",null,
             null,null,null,
             null,null
             );

        //card.setName("[NAME_SURNAME]");
        //card.setAddressZip("[ZIP]");


        stripe.createToken(card, "[pk_test_*****]", new ApiResultCallback<Token>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NotNull Token token) {
                // TODO: Send Token information to your backend to initiate a charge
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Token created: " + token.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tok = token;
                new StripeCharge(token.getId()).execute();

            }



            public void onError(Exception error) {
                Log.d("Stripe", error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public class StripeCharge extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String token;

        public StripeCharge(String token) {
            this.token = token;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    postData(name,token,""+amount);
                }
            }.start();
            return "Done";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.e("Result",s);
        }
    }

    public void postData(String description, String token,String amount) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://stripe-pay-backend-backend.herokuapp.com");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new NameValuePair() {
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return "method";
                }

                @Override
                public String getValue() {
                    return "charge";
                }
            });
            params.add(new NameValuePair() {
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return "description";
                }

                @Override
                public String getValue() {
                    return description;
                }
            });
            params.add(new NameValuePair() {
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return "source";
                }

                @Override
                public String getValue() {
                    return token;
                }
            });
            params.add(new NameValuePair() {
                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return "amount";
                }

                @Override
                public String getValue() {
                    return amount;
                }
            });

            OutputStream os = null;

            os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getQuery(params));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params)
        {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error suggests that `yearField.getText().toString()` is null. I'd add some debugging to find out why that is.

Comment: @PaulAsjes ok I will try the debugging to see what is going on. I will update you if that's not a problem